# How to add intent for imageview in fragment page?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, imageview, android-imageview

i want to add an intent for an imageview onclick which links to a weburl. below u can see the xml file of home fragment page and java file of home fragment.kindly help me with this

HomeFragment.xml

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/scial" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:src="@drawable/log" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/line" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/banner" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/mainn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

HomeFragment.java

```
package com.tabs;

import com.tabs.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a intent to one of the imageview's with the required address of webpage. Try this:

```
image.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
String url = "http://www.google.com";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding inside your onCreateView?

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "http://www.your_weburl.com";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);           
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use image button; i.e: ib_playPause
XML

```
ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/ib_play"

   android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
```

JAVA:
private ImageButton play;

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

play = (ImageButton) rootView .findViewById(R.id.ib_play);

    return rootView;
}
```

//for onclick

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri
                    .parse("https://play.google.com/store");
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
        }
    });
}
```